# How can I access the id of child elements?

Tags: javascript, css

I have managed to show the id of elements with this CSS code:

```
*[id]::before {
  content: attr(id);
  display: block;
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

Works fine for radio and checkbox elements, but does not work for elements that have no "::before" element, for example text inputs.

My thought was then to use the ::before of the parent container, but no clue how to access the id of the child then?

```
div *[id]::before {
  content: attr(child.id);
  display: block;
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

Is this possible with CSS? Or with JavaScript if it is not possible in CSS?

With JavaScript it would be really annoying because the page changes dynamically all the time.

Comment: _"Works fine for radio and checkbox elements, but does not work for elements that have no "::before" element, for example text inputs."_ - don't rely on this working for radio buttons or checkboxes either - those are `input` elements, too, and input elements _can't_ have children. Some browsers might see that differently, but it should really not be relied upon, if you want something that "works everywhere."

Comment: _"My thought was then to use the ::before of the parent container, but no clue how to access the id of the child then?"_ - a) not possible to begin with, and b) would not work properly if any element contained _more_ than one such child with an ID. What do you actually _need_ this for?

Comment: and yet with your second approach you are styling the input and not its container.. you may use `div:has(*[id])::before` to circumvent that but it won't work on firefox

Comment: i see, this is for debugging the page locally only, so a firefox or chrome only solution would be enough. @DiegoD, then i still can't access the child element, as CBroe says?

Comment: @DanielBrown plus I wasn't correct.. actually the id attribute would belong to the container so your rule wouldn't read the child.. it would just add an empty before element. CSS only wouldn't be feasible... you may try an approach that via js adds some hints but it depends on your specific scenario

Comment: I may have a solution that covers all self-closing elements that cannot be covered by the ::before solution but using js. It's a function that when invoked will add a span showing the id of such elements that can be removed selecting them through their distinctive class. But it requires such function to be called on demand or to be called repeatedly with a timer or when an event occurs like if an observable was triggered.. are you interested or are you only looking for css solution?

Comment: Whatever works! I was so happy about the CSS only idea, because I only need to inject it once the app starts. but if we can get it to fly with javascript that is okay, too.

Comment: @DanielBrown In the end I posted a new answer and deleted the old one. This new one is much more organized and easier to read plus there is no redundancy. I was glad to hear your comment there but I couldn't keep it live ... had to rewrite from scratch

Answer (score 0):

From [the MDN page on `::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before):

> Note: The pseudo-elements generated by `::before` and `::after` are boxes
> generated as if they were immediate children of the element on which
> they are applied, or the "originating element," and thus can not apply
> to replaced elements, such as `<img>`, whose content is outside the
> scope of the CSS formatting model.

But I don't think that definition is very well suited since there are many exceptions not strictly fitting with that rule and yet including element types not supporting both `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

Sometimes that problem is known to mostly affect some specific types of `<input>` elements and in general self-closing elements.

Anyway instead of relying on specific types that we want to support against the ones already supported, we'll just support any element type and we'll totally abandon the previous strategy.

The new strategy is wrapping any element to label, with a `<span>` having the class `tracked`, so that we can have a css rule that will style a `::before` pseudo-element allowed by specification whatever is the wrapped element:

```
.tracked {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}

.tracked::before {
  content: attr(data-id);
  
  position: absolute; 
  top: -1.5em;      
  left: 0;        
  z-index: 1; 
}
```

Since you said the page will change over time after loaded, we can't just rely on using a selector like `*[id]` to fetch those elements and do the operation once on `DOMContentLoaded`.

We are instead in the position to use a `MutationObserver` listening for mutation on a whole given container, so that as soon as **any new element gets added**, the element itself gets wrapped in a new `span`; or if the **`id` attribute value gets changed** for any already existing element, the wrapping `span` gets updated.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe

Such `span` will be a `display: inline-block;` element trying to affect the style of its target as less as possible and since it sets its `content` property via `attr(data-id)` inside the css rule styling its `::before` pseudo-element, it will also state the id of its contained target, inside a `data-id` data attribute.

Here I share a full demo showing how to deal with a `MutationObserver` that will keep track of elements having the `id` attribute set inside the **observed area**.

The **observed area** here is the `#container` div for the sake of keeping the demo working inside a live snippet.. because using `document.body` here would freeze everything otherwise.

Actions perfomed here:

- Initializes the observed area showing up the labels for the tracked
  elements when the document is ready; such elements include also
  regular nested divs and span to demonstrate its features beyond the
  unsupported elements;
- Shows what happens when you add new elements of 3 given types that
  wouldn't be supported by `::before` (`input[type=text]`, `textarea`,
  `select`)
- Shows what happens when an existing element you picked from a
  dropdown gets its `id` changed
- Gives you the chance to show/hide borders of tracked elements

```js
//create and return a MutationObserver that will listen for mutations on targetNode
function createDOMObserver(targetNode) {

  const subscribers = {
    newNode: [],
    idChanged: []
  };

  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
    for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.addedNodes.length) {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
          subscribers.newNode.forEach(callback => callback(node));
        });
      } else if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === 'id') {
        const prevId = mutation.oldValue;
        const newId = mutation.target.getAttribute('id');
        subscribers.idChanged.forEach(
          callback => callback(prevId, newId, mutation.target)
        );
      }
    }
  });

  const options = {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ['id'],
    attributeOldValue: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
  };

  return {
    start: function() {
      observer.observe(targetNode, options);
    },
    on: function(event, callback) {
      if (subscribers[event]) {
        subscribers[event].push(callback);
      }
    },
    disconnect: function() {
      observer.disconnect();
    }
  };
}

//on document ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{

  const observedArea = document.getElementById('container');
  const domObserver = createDOMObserver(observedArea);

  //listen for new node added in the observedArea
  domObserver.on('newNode', (node) => {
    //if the new node has an id and it's not .tracked nor .untracked
    if (node.id && !node.closest('.tracked, .untracked')) {
      console.log('New node added:', node);
      const wrapper = wrapWithTracked(node);
      refreshDropdownIds(observedArea);
    }
  });

  //listen for id attribute value change
  domObserver.on('idChanged', (prevId, newId, target) => {
    //if the affected element is already wrapped in a .tracked element
    const tracked = target.parentNode;
    if (tracked.classList.contains('tracked')) {
      console.log(`ID of element ${target.tagName} changed from ${prevId} to ${newId}`);
      tracked.setAttribute('data-id', newId);
      refreshDropdownIds(observedArea, newId);
      forceFlash(tracked);
    }
  });

  //wrap target in a span.tracked[data-id]
  function wrapWithTracked(target) {
    let wrapper = document.createElement('span');
    wrapper.className = 'tracked';
    wrapper.setAttribute('data-id', target.id);
    target.parentNode.replaceChild(wrapper, target);
    wrapper.appendChild(target);
    return wrapper;
  }

  function initLabels(container){
    const targetElements = fetchElementsToBeLabeled(container);
    targetElements.forEach( element => wrapWithTracked(element));
  }

  initLabels(observedArea);
  
  refreshDropdownIds(observedArea);

  //begin observing for mutations
  domObserver.start();

});

/*
retrieves all elements in container being qualified to be labeled
the first criteria is having the id attribute
but also not having .untracked ancestors
it gets called by the first init stage to label all existing elements
and less importantly to refresh the ids dropdown (not related to the core logic)
*/
function fetchElementsToBeLabeled(container){
  const allElements = container.querySelectorAll('*[id]');
  return [...allElements].filter(el => {
      return !el.classList.contains('untracked') && !el.closest('.untracked');
  });
}


//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Logic to add elements and to change id attribute value of existing ones
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

function newElementOnClick() {
  const selectedType = document.getElementById('elementType').value;
  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  const el = createElementOfType(selectedType, container);
}

function changeIdOnClick(){
  const id = document.getElementById('elementIDs').value;
  if(!id) return;
  const newId = generateRandomID();
  const el = changeElementId(id, newId);
}

function refreshDropdownIds(container, selectedValue = false){

  const dropdown = document.getElementById('elementIDs');
  const oldValue = dropdown.value;
  dropdown.innerHTML = '';
  const placeholderOption = document.createElement('option');
  placeholderOption.textContent = 'Please select...';  
  placeholderOption.value = ''; 
  placeholderOption.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  placeholderOption.setAttribute('selected', 'selected'); 
  dropdown.appendChild(placeholderOption);


  const targetElements = fetchElementsToBeLabeled(container);
  
  targetElements.forEach((element, i) => {
    const opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = element.id;
    opt.textContent = `${i+1}: ${element.id}`;
    dropdown.appendChild(opt);
  });
  
  if(selectedValue == false)
    dropdown.value = oldValue;
  else
    dropdown.value = selectedValue;
}

function changeElementId(id, newId){
  const el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.setAttribute('id', newId);
  return el;
}

function createElementOfType(type, container) {
    const elements = {
      'input': Object.assign(
        document.createElement('input'),
        { type: 'text', value: 'Default text for input' }
      ),
      'textarea': Object.assign(
        document.createElement('textarea'),
        { textContent: 'Default text for textarea' }
      ),
      'select': Object.assign(
        document.createElement('select'),
        { innerHTML: '<option value="default">Default Option</option>' }
      )
    };

    const element = elements[type];

    element.id = generateRandomID();
    container.appendChild(element);
    
    return element;
}


function generateRandomID(length = 8) {
  return Array.from({ length }, () => 
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'[
          Math.floor(Math.random() * 62)
      ]
  ).join('');
}

function forceFlash(element) {
  element.classList.remove('tracked');

  setTimeout(() => {
     element.classList.add('tracked');
  }, 100); 
}

function showTrackedBorders(target){
  const body = document.body;

  if (target.checked) {
      body.classList.add('show-tracked-border');
  } else {
      body.classList.remove('show-tracked-border');
  }
}
```

```css
#control {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 1em;
}

#control select {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#control button {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

#control button:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

#container {
  border: dashed 3px;
  padding: 2em 1em;
  min-height: 1em;
}

#container .area-label {
  color: #444;
  font-style: italic;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.untracked {
  border: dashed 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1.5em;
}

.untracked {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed hsl(210,8%,42%); 
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

.tracked {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}

@keyframes flashEffect {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}

.tracked::before {
  content: attr(data-id);
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: .2em;

  position: absolute; 
  top: -1.5em;      
  left: 0;        
  z-index: 1;       
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  animation: flashEffect 2s 1; 
}

.tracked *:focus {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.static{
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.show-tracked-border .tracked {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="control">
  <div>
    <select id="elementType">
      <option value="input">input[type=text]</option>
      <option value="textarea">textarea</option>
      <option value="select">select</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="newElementOnClick();">Create new element!</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    <select id="elementIDs">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Please select...</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="changeIdOnClick();">Change ID!</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showBorders" onchange="showTrackedBorders(this);">
    <label for="showBorders">
      Show borders of elements being tracked
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  
  <!-- untracked area inside the observed container -->
  <div class="untracked">
    <p class="area-label">Untracked area...</p>
    <input id="despitehavingid" value="won't be tracked">
    <select id="neitherthis">
      <option value="goodluck">good luck</option>
    </select>
    <textarea>and so on and so forth</textarea>
  </div>
  
  <p class="area-label">tracked area...</p>
  
  <input type="text" id="staticInput" class="static">
  <textarea id="staticTextarea" class="static">Default text for textarea</textarea>
  <select id="staticSelect" class="static">
    <option value="default">Default Option</option>
  </select>
  
  <div id="parentDiv" style="padding: 2em;">
    <span id="childSpan">span child</span>
    <div id="childDiv">div child</div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- ... here new elements to be tracked will be added ... -->
  
</div>
```